# ValidationAntiForgeryToken not working correctly when I enable SSL to cookies in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, ssl

I configured the SSL to cookies, HTTP to HTTPS redirection, in Web.config:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" domain="mywebsite.com" />
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" />

<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
           <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000" /><!-- enable HSTS for HTTP to HTTPS redirection -->
        </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
```

I removed some headers using Global.asax

```
Response.Headers.Remove( "Server" );

// Remove also from IIS->Select application->`HTTP Response Headers`->Remove X-Powered-By value
Response.Headers.Remove( "X-Powered-By" );
```

add:

```
Response.AddHeader( "X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN" );
```

Web page contains the simple form authentication (LogOn):

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) {
    Response.Write(Html.AntiForgeryToken());

    ...
}
%>
```

and controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult LogOn( ... ) {
   ....
}
```

An error is occurred when trying to login

```
The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_AbcDef89588" is not present.
```

What I have to do to work ?

Thanks